# Firebase Functions Error while deploying to emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to start new Firebase Functions project using latest versions of packages.

I've followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/DYfP-UIKxH0:

1. Firebase login
2. Firebase init
3. Created functions project the same way as tutorial says
4. Uncommented index.ts content
5. After that I get this error:

`Starting @google-cloud/functions-emulator
[2018-04-04T19:05:12.124Z] Parsing function triggers
[2018-04-04T19:05:12.404Z] Error while deploying to emulator: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/client/rest-client.js:34:42)
    at getService.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/client/rest-client.js:33:16)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
⚠  functions: Failed to emulate helloWorld`

I have latest functions emulator *1.0.0-beta4.
All other libs are in latest versions...

I'm at point where I have no idea how to debug this better and how to resolve this

Comment: That tutorial doesn't do anything with the emulator.  What are exactly are you doing that goes outside its script?

Comment: That's true.
I'm running: `firebase serve --only functions`
I also downgraded node to 6.11.5 because at start there was error message that I can't use latest version

Comment: I don't know what's going on here.  Local emulation works fine, and it will get demonstrated in the next video in that series.  Maybe recreate everything from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs if an existing process listens on port 5000. Double check if there's a process running, e.g. on Mac OS Sierra

```
sudo lsof -n -iTCP:5000 | grep LISTEN
```

Stop this process or run firebase on another port, e.g.

```
firebase -p 7777 serve --only functions
```

No need to reinstall packages. Error message is not helpful and we spent some time to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was due other app that was listening on port 5001!

Firebase serve stops with some weird message.
Just check as answer below if ports aren't busy